# Can't delete an Azure backup vault

Tags: azure

I am trying to delete a backup vault. I deleted the storage account related to my backup vault first. After that I am unable to delete that vault. It is throwing error whenever I am trying to delete backup vault. I already tried the powershell solution in this documentation.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-delete-vault

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I suppose you need to delete backups inside of it

Comment: @Jarnstrom I actually removed storage account associated with the backup vault before stopping backup jobs.

Comment: @AbdulWahab I was asking if you could paste the error message you get when you try to delete the vault. Usually it gives you a hint of what is wrong .

Comment: @Jarnstrom Yesterday I am about to paste the error message here, But I have done one more research on the topic and find the answer from below link.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404847/how-to-delete-azure-recovery-services-vault). Any way I appreciate you guys for all your help.

Comment: @AbdulWahab Glad that all worked out in the end.